# Spring websocket security for multiple users

Tags: java, spring, spring-security, websocket, spring-websocket

I want to use websocket in spring application for contact requests. I already have setup login page for users and I use spring security for that. My problem is following: how to securely send web socket messages to two different users.

I know that i can broadcast messages to every user subscribed to some topic with `@SendTo()` and can broadcast message to one user only with something like

```
messagingTemplate
    .convertAndSendToUser(principal.getName(), "/queue/requests", request);
```

because his username is stored in principal.

My problem is how to handle when we have to target 2 users from a request and make it secure so that you cant just listen to any channels from client side without being authorized.

Ideally I'm looking for something like

```
messagingTemplate
    .convertAndSendToUser(request.getFromUser(), "/queue/requests", request) 

messagingTemplate
    .convertAndSendToUser(request.getToUser(), "/queue/requests", request)
```

Comment: I think you need Spring Security 4 for this, and Spring Boot uses Spring Security 3..."Spring Security 4.0 has introduced authorization support for WebSockets"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Spring WebSocket handles /user channel, so I used those methods

This is how I solved this problem:

When user authenticates with Spring Security, WebSocket module creates unique channel for that user based on his Principal. Example `"/user/queue/position-updates"` is translated to `"/queue/position-updates-user123"`

So on the client side all I had to do, was subscribe to `/user/queue/requests`

And on the server side, send messages to `/user/{username}/queue/requests` with `convertAndSendToUser(request.getFromUser(), "/queue/requests", request)` and Spring handles the rest.

Comment: thats what i was trying to tell you..:)

Answer (score 0):

You can do something as follows given in [Spring-websocket-chat](https://github.com/salmar/spring-websocket-chat).
At client side you can have `/app/chat.private.{targetUser}`

At Server side you can get target user by using `@DestinationVariable` and source user from `Principal`

```
@MessageMapping("/chat.private.{username}")
    public void filterPrivateMessage(@Payload ChatMessage message, @DestinationVariable("username") String username, Principal principal) {
        checkProfanityAndSanitize(message);

        message.setUsername(principal.getName());

        simpMessagingTemplate.convertAndSend("/user/" + username + "/queue/chat.message", message);
    }
```

Comment: This is insecure because any user can subscribe to any channel

Comment: You can add websocket security and give access to particular channel to particular user by using spring security

Comment: so you want the two user receiving message are not authorized